# Should I erase my iPhone if lost/stolen?

Tags: iphone, backup

The recommended procedure is: Erase the phone immediately if stolen. But if the phone has a passcode and no-one can break into it anyway, can erasing be safely disregarded altogether?

The upside of not erasing would be if that the iPhone is found, all data would still be there.

Comment: So basically you answered your own question...

Comment: You *can* do whatever you want. What are you really asking?

Answer (score 2):

Just like @Lucas Kauffman said: "you already answered your own question."

The only way for someone to gain access to your lost iPhone, is when they know the pin. Otherwise they can't gain access to your iPhone.
By making weekly/monthly back-ups to iCloud of your device, you are able to recover everything in case your iPhone gets lost/stolen.

Depending on which iPhone you have, you can use the option to erase all the data on the iPhone after 10 wrong pin attempts.